# How to configure two addresses to access other frontends/port

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, router, apache2

How do I configure two addresses to access other frontends / different ports, for example:

| Address | Mapping to |
| --- | --- |
| [www.mysite.com/config](http://www.mysite.com/config) | (nodejs) localhost:3000 |
| [www.mysite.com/client](http://www.mysite.com/client) | (django) localhost:7000 |

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use the Search

- in case you would have used the words "apache proxy" you would found similar questions like

  - [Apache reverse proxy to docker container](https://serverfault.com/questions/884862/apache-reverse-proxy-to-docker-container)
  - and a lot more similar questions

## Solution to not overkill your Brain in an Example

#### Apache

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.example.com


    ProxyPass /config http://localname:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /config http://localname:3000/

    ProxyPass /client http://localname:7000/
    ProxyPassReverse /client http://localname:7000/
</VirtualHost>
```

#### Nginx (just in case you may need it)

```
location /config {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
location /client {
    proxy_pass              http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
}
```